# Where/How Do I Add Backbone.js to Home.aspx Without Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

Is there a way to add an external javascript file to Home.aspx? I tried to add it to the Content PlaceHolder - PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead but it didn't work (meaning that the link did not appear in Developer Tools and the test "alert" didn't fire).

I also tried to add a Script Editor Webpart but was also unsuccessful.

I already have three JavaScript Display Templates styling lists on the page and they work fine. What I need to do now is to add a backbone.js corporate directory application to the page and none of the documentation I read showed me HOW to insert the js file so that it would fire after document.ready.

I have read about creating a visual webpart in VS2012/VS2013 to add Backbone to a page but our network engineer has not been able to correctly configure our site collection for VS app development so I am trying to find a workaround solution so that I can meet my deadline even if he fails to meet his.

The Visual Studio issue is that when I press F5 to test the build, the build completes properly but I am presented with a credential dialog that will not allow ANYONE to log in through. I am a site collection admin and site admin on the site collection and I still get access denied after the build and our network guy can't solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Visual Studio issue is that when I press F5 to test the build, the build completes properly but I am presented with a credential dialog that will not allow ANYONE to log in through. I am a site collection admin and site admin on the site collection and I still get access denied after the build and our network guy can't solve this.

This sounds like old Loopback Check - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-gb

Is this SharePoint 2013? Try disabling the Minimal Download Strategy Feature (in Site Features) then retry your methods. I've found this interferes with third party libraries.

Comment: I forwarded your suggestion on the Loopback Check to the network guy and he is working on that ... thanks!

Comment: I disabled Minimal Download Strategy and re-added the js file  in the Content PlaceHolder - PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead but the file is still not showing in Developer Tools. The file only has a document ready function with alert('loaded'); in it but I get nothing.

Comment: Try again to add a `<script />` tag inside a Script Editor Web Part. You might need two, one to reference your library and the second with the code you want to run (in this case, the simply `alert()` in the document ready function.